# Specific term in UX for the task of comparing Visual Design files with developed HTML pages?

Tags: terminology, html, visual-design, comparison

Is there an UX/design terminology for the task of comparing Visual Design files with developed HTML pages?

As of now, I am referring to it as VD comparison or VD compliance check. Please help me to get the specific term.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime we call it "UX Review" and sometimes we call it a "Build Review" since we're reviewing both the styling of UI elements and UX functionality in a product's current build.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a formal UX terminology for what you are describing, although some people would call this a Design Review.

Where this fits in the development process will depend on the development methodology.

For example, if you are following any of the Agile development methodologies, you start each Sprint by showing the team what you want them to build (e.g. talk through the design with everyone) and at the end of every sprint there should be a Sprint Review meeting where the team review everything that was created in the sprint. There will also be a Retrospective meeting where the team will talk about what worked and what did not.

So in Agile development methodologies there are ample chances to compare the design to the developed work, which allows you to highlight any deltas if they exist.

Irrespective of the development methodology your team follows, from a UX Design perspective it is important to keep regular tabs on progress to keep everyone honest, i.e. we should not be chucking designs out of an ivory tower hoping that development will get it.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a number of teams. The only term I've heard used with any frequency is ...

> "**Visual QA**"

For the record, this isn't technically a UX thing. If your UX team also handles the final product design, then it falls in their court. But it's definitely something for the product / brand / visual design role to confirm.